# How to get userId from Onsignal Flutter on App start?

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I am facting an issue related to OneSignal response user-id: null on App start.
I want to get device state on Application Running on main flutter.

Is there any posibile way to acheived this, please kindly give me the advice.
Thank you!!

**Note**
The issue only when first install

```
void main() async {
  var widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await _initController();
  initNotification();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(const TLCustomerApp());
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ListTile(
            minLeadingWidth: 10,
            leading: Icon(Icons.error_outline),
            title: Text("There is something went wrong,\n please try again!"),
          ),
        ),
      );
  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}


void initNotification() async {
  OneSignal.shared.setAppId(oneSignalKey);
  final status = await OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState();
  final String? osUserID = status?.userId;
  print("==>SUBSCRIBE_ID:${osUserID}");
  OneSignal.shared.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler((OSNotificationReceivedEvent event) {event.complete(event.notification);
  });
  OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
    var data = result.notification.additionalData;
    // if (data != null) {
    //   var routeName = data["routeName"];
    //   Get.toNamed(routeName);
    // }
  });
  OneSignal.shared.setPermissionObserver((OSPermissionStateChanges changes) {});
  OneSignal.shared
      .setSubscriptionObserver((OSSubscriptionStateChanges changes) {});
  OneSignal.shared.setEmailSubscriptionObserver(
      (OSEmailSubscriptionStateChanges emailChanges) {});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add this in your code and you get onesignal user"userId".

```
 OneSignal.shared.setSubscriptionObserver((OSSubscriptionStateChanges changes) {
    //  print(changes.to.userId);
   String? userId = changes.to.userId ?? '';
   if (userId != '') {
     registerUserId(userId);
   }
 });
```

Comment: @JamesNavath Please vote so other can also find useful solution. :)

Comment: Sorry, my reputation less than 15, I can not wote

Comment: @NitinGadhiya i tried this solution but it says "The function 'registerUserId' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'registerUserId', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'registerUserId'.dartundefined_function"

Comment: @abrev
I am utilizing the "registerUserId" function to store the "userId" in the database from my end, therefore please disregard this function. 
Thanks.